# Как сделать эффект левитирующего блока как в примере

Tags: javascript, css

https://itproger.com/ [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как сделать подобный блок на своем сайте ?

Comment: Называется [параллакс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME тут скорее `mousemove parallax effect` - [1](https://codepen.io/oscicen/pen/zyJeJw) [2](https://codepen.io/eugene_burlak/pen/grQbxw)

Answer (score 1):

```js
// самое интересное здесь
const imgs = [...document.querySelectorAll('img')]; // берем все изображения, которые будем паралаксить

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => { // вешаем обработчик, который следит за перемещением мышки
  const { clientX, clientY } = e; // получаем координаты курсора
  
  imgs.forEach(img => {// для каждого изображения в массиве делаем операцию
    const speed = img.getAttribute('data-speed'); // получаем атрибут speed каждого изображения
    img.style.transform = `translate(${-clientX / speed}px, ${-clientY / speed}px)`; // двигаем изображения с помощью стиля transform
  });
});
```

```css
/* и здесь ничего важного */
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 400px;
  background: url(https://pngimg.com/uploads/blood/blood_PNG6114.png) center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  transition: transform .5s; // кроме этого. задает плавность анимации
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img
    src="https://s.tcdn.co/0b3/15f/0b315faa-2cfb-3a1f-80c5-458d72948516/3.png"
    data-speed="5"
  />
  <img
    src="https://s.tcdn.co/fcb/7f8/fcb7f8aa-d7a3-31d2-ba8b-ae97676501aa/2.png"
    data-speed="20"
  />
</div>
```

---

- атрибут `speed` в каждом изображении - это коэфициент скорости движения изображения при паралаксе. он не обязателен. но без него все изображения будут двигаться с одинаковой скоростью
- всё остальное описание в комментариях кода
- божми - тоже люди

Answer (score 0):

На сайте itproger.com используется [parallax.js](http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/) с помощью него легко сделать такой эффект.